# VBA How do I check if userform combobox values already exist in a database

Tags: excel, vba, search, combobox, userform

I am self taught in vba and I am currently building a form based inventory control system for my company that converts materials into bespoke sizes. Due to the bespoke nature of the business depending on the customer, size of base material used etc. there can be myriad different off cuts or finished products put into stock after the base material has been used. Consequently it is difficult to know if this product already exists in the database (FinPriceList) without actually scrolling through and looking for it. I therefore am looking for a method to check if the product exists in the table FinPriceList (columns A,B,C & D respectively) using vba to cross reference the input from the comboboxes Product Group (FinProdGroup), Product Category "FinProdCat", Product Description "FinProdDesc" and the text box Product Size "FinProdSize" from the userform FinProdUserForm.

My current attempt is as follows, therefore any help would be appreciated:

```
Sub VerifyStock()
Const DQTE = """"

Dim criteria1 As String
Dim criteria2 As String
Dim criteria3 As String
Dim criteria4 As String
Dim evalStr As String
Dim prodCode As Variant

criteria1 = FinProdIn.FinProdGroupIn.Value 'combobox1 from userform
criteria2 = FinProdIn.FinProdCatIn.Value   'combobox2 from userform
criteria3 = FinProdIn.FinProdDescIn.Value  'combobox3 from userform
criteria4 = FinProdIn.FinProdSizeIn.Value  'combobox4 from userform
evalStr = "INDEX(FinishedPriceList,MATCH(" & DQTE & criteria1 & DQTE & "&" & DQTE & criteria2 & DQTE & "&" & DQTE & criteria3 & DQTE & "&" & DQTE & criteria4 & DQTE & ",FinPriceList!$A:$A&FinPriceList!$B:$B&FinPriceList!$C:$C&FinPriceList!$D:$D,0))"
prodCode = Evaluate(evalStr)

If VarType(prodCode) = vbError Then
    MsgBox "Not Found! Would you like to add new product to stock list?", vbYesNo
    If Response = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        Unload FinProdIn
    Else
    Call ModuleAddtoFinPriceList.AddtoFinPriceList
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Product found would you like to add a transaction?", vbYesNo
    If Response = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled"
        Unload FinProdIn
    Else
        Call ModuleAddTrans.AddTrans
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Index](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-HP005209138.aspx) and [Match](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx) worksheet functions combined with the [Evaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223886%28v=office.11%29.aspx) VBA method.  For example, if your product code (or partnumber, or other identifier) is in the range A2:A5000, and you have two criteria to match in B2:B5000 and C2:C5000, you could use:

```
Sub FindVal()
    Const DQTE = """"

    Dim criteria1 As String
    Dim criteria2 As String
    Dim evalStr As String
    Dim prodCode As Variant

    criteria1 = "ABC"
    criteria2 = "DEF"
    evalStr = "INDEX($C$2:$C$5000,MATCH(" & DQTE & criteria1 & DQTE & "&" & DQTE & criteria2 & DQTE & ",$A$2:$A$5000&$B$2:$B$5000,0))"

    prodCode = Evaluate(evalStr)

    If VarType(prodCode) = vbError Then
        MsgBox "No match found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value found: " & prodCode
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Geoff, thanks very much for your prompt response. I have attempted to implement this, however I keep getting a "runtime error 13 - Type Mismatch" for the `prodCode = Evaluate(evalStr)` line of your code. Have you any suggestions as to why?

Comment: I added an edit: the prodCode in my example above would sometimes take on an error type result, so changing it to a variant allows you to test for that.

Comment: Hi Geoff, I have added the edit to my code, however now it returns  my equivalent of "no match found" whether the product exists in the table or not. If I repost my updated code as an answer, could you have a look and see if there is anything glaring that I have missed?

Comment: Sure - but rather than posting the updated code as an answer, edit your question and put it as a second code block.

Comment: I suspect that something is either wrong with your named `FinishedPriceList` range, or your criteria retrieval.  Also, is the name of your sheet (`FinPriceList`) correct?  Literally when I paste your code into a new workbook, define a range called `FinishedPriceList` on column E, rename the sheet to `FinPriceList`, then it works.